# Force user mode program to run under non paged memory

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, process, operating-system

I need to write a program (prefebly in a high-level language like C# or Java but can be C/C++) that must never have its data written to disk under no circumstances.

even without implementing any I/O operations, data can be written to disk by the OS page faults.

Is there anyway to aviod it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Is it possible to split your program into a client and server where the server controls the data and the client just interfaces to it? This would circumvent your requirement.

Comment: And you do understand that anything in memory can be written to disk by forcing a memory dump of the process.

Comment: @HansPassant updated

Comment: Very hard to guess why you would imagine this could be your solution, but almost certainly you completely misunderstand how easy it will be for an attacker to read your memory, if they are able to access the disk.

Comment: @BoPersson If only every developers requirement would have an answer for that question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *"you completely misunderstand how easy it will be for an attacker to read your memory, if they are able to access the disk."* -- This assumes an **online** attack. If you store a password in memory and it never touches the disk, an **offline** attack to compromise the password is impossible. (I'm not sure if that's the goal, just pointing out that your assertion is technically incorrect.)

Comment: @Omribitan My client can wish for software that inflates / deflates the Moon at the press of a button but that clearly won't happen. Dumb requirements don't necessarily translate to code.

Comment: Remove the hard disk from the computer?  IE how much control do you have over the hardware environment?

Comment: @cdhowie Online is generally much easier than offline, so it would be odd to defend against offline first

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's a different assertion -- you're moving the goalposts now. If an online admin/root-level attack is successful, it's pretty much game over. If an offline attack is successful, only information written to storage is compromised for sure.  Even if offline attacks succeed less often, there is still merit to protecting against them.

Comment: The "motivation" behind this task is to garantee that data can never be recoverd after its deletion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : if the system is always offline (let us play devil's advocate), then there would be no requirement to worry about being online and it may actually be valuable to deal with the offline security issues. The primary issue with this entire question is that we don't know the requirements and specifications of this user.

Comment: @Omribitan What sort of attacks are you wanting to defend against? Have you considered using secure strings?

Comment: And I presume your software will also disable the "hibernate" function of the OS? And disable debuggers?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan l looking to assure that assuming the data in the program is cleared, it can never be recoverd.

Comment: `The "motivation" behind this task is to garantee that data can never be recovered after its deletion.` and you're worried about physical access (not only online), right? Then how any C# (or C++) program will stop me from directly grabbing data at the RAM connection? etc.etc. ... I fear you don't need a *software* solution.

Comment: @Omribitan You need to describe under what situation you're trying to ensure this. As it was already mentioned, one can attach a debugger to your process and have access to _all_ data in the process. The same is true for a memory dump. Keeping data exclusively in memory doesn't protect it against anything. You either need to use very heavy encryption or remove the data to a machine you control. In either of these cases you don't need to worry about swapping, etc.

Comment: Like I keep saying, I am not trying to protect sensitive data from being exposed. I'm trying to assure that ONCE it has been deleted by the program, It can NEVER be recoverd.

Comment: What sort of attacks are you looking to defend against?

Comment: @Omribitan Me getting sensitive data to my own PC prevents any safe final deletion on yours, because I still have it. I think you indeed want to prevent leaking infos (too).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan We want to build an In memory distributed file system for small data (like Spark but for tiny data). **Why?** say you are wroking on a doc file in a the MOST secure environment that can never be hacked into (hypothetically). After a while you are deleting this file when you have only one thing on your mind - no body can EVER know what was written in that file. Not even if someone will come, take the harddrive out and send it to some lab for recovery. EVER.

Comment: @Omribitan So, should your file system be a) secure itself, or b) rely on a secure hardware device and environment? Don't mix that. If b, just write it and trust the device/environment to be unhackable (yes, the application software needs some security stuff too, but not management of hardware). If a, again: It can't be done with software alone. ... Btw., for such hypothetical ultra-secure stuff, WIndows is the wrong choice. And userland programs for Windows file systems are the wrong choice too.

Comment: I don't understand why people give -ve votes if someone asked a question which is generally considered bad practice. When I read this question, I thought, it would give me a way to understand internals of system. IMO -ve votes should be given if the person, who asked the question has not done his homework enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows systems, [`VirtualLock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895%28VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to lock individual regions of memory.  I am not aware of any options to lock all memory pages for the entire process.  You would have to use this function on a memory allocation immediately before you store sensitive data in it.

On POSIX systems, this can be achieved by using the [`mlock()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) family of functions within the process that shouldn't be swapped.  For example, this will prevent swapping of currently-mapped memory pages as well as any pages that become mapped in the future:

```
mlockall(MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE);
```

On some systems, locking memory pages is a privileged operation.  You would have to check the details of your particular system.

Comment: On Windows, you would also need to disable hibernation.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Not only on Windows! This would affect other platforms, too.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest solution is to store everything (including the hibernation file) on an encrypted disk. Technically all the bits would still be on disk, but they're meaningless without the key.

Note that this doesn't hide the bits in your application from the authorized user. It's not a DRM scheme. But note that a determined user could undo any type of memory page protection anyway.